# Maximise a function over real and complex parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

I have the function

```
f[b_x_] := Exp[-I b] Sin[I x],
```

where $x$ is real and $b$ is complex. I want to maximise the function $f$ over $x$ and $b$, but it is returning real values for both. How can I tell Mathematica that $b$ is complex?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You cannot (conventionally) order complex numbers, so as written, your question is invalid.  Can you explain what you would like to maximise (magnitude of `f`, real part of `f`?)

Comment: Why is that? I don't follow what you mean with the ordering. But it is the magnitude of $f$ that should be maximised.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the relevant mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

By default, symbols are complex-valued, so your function is:

```
f[b_, x_] := Exp[-I b] Sin[I x];
```

Simplifying:

```
FullSimplify[f[b, x], x \[Element] Reals]
(I Cos[b] + Sin[b]) Sinh[x]
```

But Sinh[x] goes to infinity as x increases, so there is no maximum for this function.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
f[a_, b_, x_] := Exp[-(a + I b)] Sin[I x]
```

and minimize for real `a,b,x`

```
NMinimize[Conjugate[f[a, b, x]] f[a, b, x], {a, b, x}]
(*{6.831*10^-84 + 0. I, {a -> 94.7264, b -> 33.707, x -> 0.352703}}*)
```

Comment: Note that the OP asked for maximization.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks,  maximization seems to be an ill posed question??? ...